# From look-at vectors to a quaternion

Tags: mathematics, matrix, quaternion

So, I have code to create a **quaternion** from a **matrix** ([using the 3x3 rotational part](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/).)

And I have code to construct a transformation matrix from a **lookat + up** vector pair.

To go from lookat+up to quaternion, I can thus go via the matrix intermediary:

```
vec3 lookat;
vec3 up;
...
mat44 trf = mat44::create_basis( lookup, up );
quat ori = quat::from_matrix( trf );
```

So far, so good.

But can I do this without the matrix intermediary?
Because it seems to inefficient. For starters, both the lookat+up and the quaternion are a lot more concise than the intermediate matrix. It goes from compact to large, to the most compact.

How can I create a quaternion using just a look-at vector and an up-vector, both of which are guaranteed to be unit length and perpendicular to each other.

Comment: Are you guaranteed the look at and up vectors are unit vectors, and exactly perpendicular, or do we have to accommodate cases that depart from this simplest version?

Comment: Is this similar to what you are looking for? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60511/quaternion-for-an-object-that-to-point-in-a-direction